# SendGrid does not send emails in my ASP.NET Core MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, sendgrid, email-validation, asp.net-core-identity

Whenever I click the register button, the page appears asking to check the email for confirmation but the email never arrives.

I already configured the key, I already made a console application and it worked, but when I implement it in my project, after registration, the email is not sent, my application was built entirely in scaffold identity

`AuthMessageSenderOptions.cs`:

```
namespace aluguel.Services
{
    public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
    {
        public string? SendGridKey { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`EmailSender.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

namespace aluguel.Services
{
    public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor,
                           ILogger<EmailSender> logger)
        {
            Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; } //Set with Secret Manager.

        public async Task SendEmailAsync(string toEmail, string subject, string message)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Options.SendGridKey))
            {
                throw new Exception("Null SendGridKey");
            }
            await Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, toEmail);
        }

        public async Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string toEmail)
        {
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("Joe@contoso.com", "Password Recovery"),
                Subject = subject,
                PlainTextContent = message,
                HtmlContent = message
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(toEmail));

            // Disable click tracking.
            // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
            msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
            _logger.LogInformation(response.IsSuccessStatusCode
                                   ? $"Email to {toEmail} queued successfully!"
                                   : $"Failure Email to {toEmail}");
        }
    }
}
```

and the `program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using aluguel.Areas.Identity.Data;
using aluguel.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContextConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'ApplicationDbContextConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

builder.Services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(builder.Configuration);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

Comment: Hi,@NÍCOLAS DINIZ DE CASTILHO  ,have you debugged and checked var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);  what's going wrong?

Comment: I do not see something wrong with your code. Do you see your email in the [Email Activity Feed](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/analytics-and-reporting/email-activity-feed)? Are you getting any errors? What's the response body from `client.SendEmailAsync`?

Comment: I wrote this guide for using SendGrid and identity emails which may help: https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-send-asp-net-core-identity-emails-with-twilio-sendgrid